# How to dump Yaml object into File?

Tags: java, file-io, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a simple java program which is using snakeyaml to read the yaml file and I have edited some values of yaml object. But I am unable to dump the object back to yaml file. Not sure whats the right way to dumping the yaml object to file.

Heres the code

```
       InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml")); 
        Writer output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileWriter("/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(input);
        System.out.println("yaml data is " +data.get("saved_caches_directory"));
        data.put("saved_caches_directory", "/var/lib/cassandra/saved_new_caches");
        yaml.dump(data, output);
        System.out.println(output.toString());
        output.write(data);  // Error in this line.

    }
```

I need the yaml.dump() to dump the modified yaml object back to the file. I am not sure how the write happens in there. According to eclipse yaml.dump(data, output); method is availabe where output is writer object. I am not sure how to instantiate the write object to send it back to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a Writer

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter("/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml");
```

To dump the data to the writer

```
yaml.dump(data, writer);
```

To close the writer when you are finished

```
writer.close();
```

Comment: I did had tried the same earlier. I think i found my problem. My input stream and output writer were initialized one after the another. which for some reason truncated my file, so there was no content to be read. ..

Comment: @Rahul Agreed, don't open a file for reading until after you have written AND closed it.